# Converting stored procedure resultset to GroupBy in LINQ

Tags: linq, entity-framework, stored-procedures

My stored procedure returns the following data:

```
PersonId PersonName RootId RootName
    1       A          1      X
    1       A          2      Y
```

Person can have more than one `RootId`. I want to group this data on `PersonId`

```
  Class Data {
             int PersonId;
             string personname;
             List<Root> Roots
          }

  Class Root {
           int   RootId;
           string RootName;
             }
```

I want to Convert my stored procedure output to a `List<Data>()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like the following:

```
var data = sprocResults
    .GroupBy(p => p.PersonId)
    .Select(g => new Data
    {
        PersonId = g.Key,
        personname = g.First().PersonName,
        Roots = g.Select(r => new Root
        {
            RootId = r.RootId,
            RootName = r.RootName
        }).ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```